# GitHub - changed username while there is an pending invite - any effects on invite?

Tags: github

I invited a collaborator to my public repo.
After that, I changed my username.
The invitation is still pending.
Will there be any conflicts or problems for the invited collaborator? Or can he still join the repo via the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be fine. The invitation is linked to your account, not your username. Although the email they received might contain your old username and that might confuse your potential collaborator.

To be sure, issue another invite.

Links and references using your previous username will still work until someone takes over that username and makes repos with the same names.

See ["Changing your GitHub username"](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/changing-your-github-username) for more.